# Fit elements in parent from top to bottom?

Tags: html, css

I'm styling a blog feed, I have two classes of elements .big-box and .small-box. On desktop the first has a 60% width and the second 40% and both have variable heights.

```
<div>
   <div class="big-box"></div>
   <div class="small-box"></div>
   <div class="big-box"></div>
   <div class="small-box"></div>
   <div class="big-box"></div>
   <div class="small-box"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to fit from top to bottom inside their container, while still being able to keep the order on mobile:

[image]

I know there are jQuery like the masonry plugin, but since the elements have a fixed width I'm hoping there is a simpler way to do it. Is this possible just with css? If not, what's the next easier way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "fit from top to bottom inside their container" ?

Comment: Will they always alternate in the HTML?

Comment: Just make two column divs and fit the relevant boxes into each. Much simpler.

Comment: @Paulie_D I cannot make two column divs, the reason is that it should be responsive and on mobile there will be only one column (which should alternate between both sizes)

Comment: @web-tiki I mean that every element should be located as close to the top it can get

Comment: Will the boxes have a consistent height?

Comment: no, that's what prevents me from using float:left

Comment: What is the CSS now? Perhaps a JSFiddle? Barring flexbox or JS/JQ, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I looked into a similar issue on one of my sites previously. I ended up creating two DIVs and adding the elements as children to the appropriate DIV. When the page width got too small, I hid the second DIV and moved it's children into the correct locations within the first DIV, vice-versa for small screen to big. This was based on assigning IDs to the boxes that I could use to order the elements when reordering. This worked for me because my main concern was mobile vs. desktop not someone resizing their desktop browser. if this seems like an option for you, I can dig up the code I was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can almost achieve this using the bootstrap grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Check my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ben1/Wb9gL/2/

The only issue you have is with having different div heights. Bootstrap solves that by using clearfix divs: -

```
<div class="clearfix visible-md"></div>
```

If you can't access the html you might be able to inject the clearfix divs through scripting, though the box top's won't line up as per your diagram (try changing the html frame width on my jsfiddle to see what happens).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way (if you need all sizes with %):

http://jsfiddle.net/Thq53/4/

The html structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="big"></div>
        <div class="big"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="small"></div>
        <div class="small"></div>
        <div class="small"></div>
        <div class="small"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot do it. I need to keep the structure, both because I haven't got access to the html and because I need to make it responsive (and if I "dropped" .right on mobile the elements would have the wrong order)